# Uncertainty-minimizing stratified sampling strategy

Tags: weighted-sampling

Suppose there is a school, and I want to know what proportion of students like the color red better than green, or vice versa (suppose there is no "other" option, just a binary variable). The school is 70% female and 30% male for some reason.

The assumption is that females have some (unknown) probability of preferring red, and males have a different, unknown probability of preferring red.

I have time to ask 100 people which color they prefer.

After I ask 100 people, I will estimate the overall proportion of red-likers by estimating female-proportion-of-red-likers and male-proportion-of-red-likers and weighting these two according to the prevalence of females and males.

How many females should I ask, and how many males, to minimize the uncertainty of my resulting estimate?

(An ideal answer would connect this to a larger theory for the case of N strata each of which has an independently drawn unknown Bernoulli parameter. Bonus points if it extends to a Bayesian setting where the prior is non-uniform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We call them population partition A and B which is more neutral than male/female while staying equivalent.

Say there is a proportion $f$ of subset A in the population, a probability $p_A$ for that category of having the trait considered, resp. $f_B$ and $p_B$ for the subset B. We are trying to estimate: 
$$P = f p_A + f_B p_B$$

Out of the $N$ sample we do, we sample a proportion $\alpha_A$ of population $A$ and $\alpha_B$ of popoulation $B$. An stratified estimator of $P$ is:
$$\hat{P} = f_a \sum_{i=1}^{\alpha_A N}{I_i^A} + f_B p_B \sum_{i=1}^{\alpha_B N}{I_i^B}$$

To minimize the estimation uncertainty, we need to minimise its variance, which is:
$$N^2 Var(\hat{P}) = f_a^2 \frac{1}{\alpha_A^2} p_A (1-p_A) + f_B^2 \frac{1}{\alpha_B} p_B (1-p_B)$$
using our sampling proportion $\alpha = \alpha_A = 1-\alpha_b \in [0,1]$.

The optimal proportion to sample is therefore:
$$\alpha = \arg \min_{\alpha \in [0,1]}  \frac{1}{\alpha^2} f_a^2 p_A (1-p_A) +\frac{1}{(1-\alpha)^2}  f_B^2 p_B (1-p_B)$$

Therefore, we need the value of $p_A$ and $p_B$ (or estimates thereof) to determine (or estimate) the optimal sampling proportion $\alpha$.